# Representing 'not in' subquery as join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am trying to convert the following query:

```
select *
from employees
where emp_id not in (select distinct emp_id from managers);
```

into a form where I represent the subquery as a join. I tried doing:

```
select *
from employees a, (select distinct emp_id from managers) b
where a.emp_id!=b.emp_id;
```

I also tried:

```
select *
from employees a, (select distinct emp_id from managers) b
where a.emp_id not in b.emp_id;
```

But it does not give the same result. I have tried the 'INNER JOIN' syntax as well, but to no avail. I have become frustrated with this seemingly simple problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/  This has helped me, and others more than I care to mention.

Comment: @xQbert Thank you! That does help. However, can somebody explain to me why my approach didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select e.*
from employees e
left join managers m on e.emp_id = m.emp_id
where m.emp_id is null
```

This will join the two tables.  Then we discard all rows where we found a matching manager and are left with employees who aren't managers.

Comment: I'd like to choose this as the answer, but I don't have enough reputation to do so. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Assume employee Data set of

```
Emp_ID
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Assume Manger data set of

```
Emp_ID
1
2
3
4
5
8
9

select *
from employees
where emp_id not in (select distinct emp_id from managers);
```

The above isn't joining tables so no Cartesian product is generated... you just have 7 records you're looking at...

The above would result in 6 and 7  Why? only 6 and 7 from Employee Data isn't in the managers table. 8,9 in managers is ignored as you're only returning data from employee.

```
select *
from employees a, (select distinct emp_id from managers) b
where a.emp_id!=b.emp_id;
```

The above didnt' work because a Cartesian product is generated... All of Employee to all of Manager (assuming 7 records in each table 7*7=49)
so instead of just evaluating the employee data like you were in the first query. Now you also evaluate all managers to all employees

so Select * results in

```
1,1
1,2
1,3
1,4
1,5
1,8
1,9
2,1
2,2...
```

Less the where clause matches... 
so 7*7-7 or 42. and while this may be the answer to the life universe and everything in it, it's not what you wanted.

I also tried:

```
select *
from employees a, (select distinct emp_id from managers) b
where a.emp_id not in b.emp_id;
```

Again a Cartesian... All of Employee to ALL OF Managers

So this is why a left join works

```
SELECT e.*
FROM employees e
LEFT OUTER JOIN managers m
  on e.emp_id = m.emp_id
WHERE m.emp_id is null
```

This says join on ID first... so don't generate a Cartesian but actually join on a value to limit the results. but since it's a LEFT join return EVERYTHING from the LEFT table (employee) and only those that match from manager.

so in our example would be returned as e.emp_Di = m.Emp_ID

```
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
5,5
6,NULL
7,NULL
```

now the where clause so

```
6,Null
7,NULL are retained...
```

older ansii SQL standards for left joins would have been *= in the where clause...

```
select *
from employees a, managers b
where a.emp_id *= b.emp_id  --I never remember if the * is the LEFT so it may be =*
and b.emp_ID is null;
```

But I find this notation harder to read as the join can get mixed in with the other limiting criteria...

Answer (score 1):

Use `Left Outer Join` instead

```
select e.*
from employees e
left outer join managers m
on e.emp_id = m.emp_id
where m.emp_id is null
```

left outer join will preserve the rows from `m` table even if they do not have a match i `e` table based on the `emp_id` field. The we filter on `where m.emp_id is null` - give me all the rows from `e` where there's no matching record in `m` table. 
A bit more on the subject can be found here:

[Visual representation of joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

`from employees a, (select distinct emp_id from managers) b` implies `cross join` - all posible combinations between tables (and you needed `left outer join` instead)

Comment: Thank you! That works. But can you explain to me why my approach wasn't working? The logic seemed alright to me.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would probably be a left join:

```
select
    e.*
from employees e
left join managers m on e.emp_id = m.emp_id
where
m.emp_id is null;
```

The idea here is you're saying that you want to select everything from employees, including anything that matches in the manager table based on emp_id and then filtering out the rows that actually have something in the manager table.

Answer (score 0):

The `MINUS` keyword should do the trick:

```
SELECT e.* FROM employees e
MINUS
Select m.* FROM managers m
```

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from employees
where Not (emp_id in (select distinct emp_id from managers));
```